# Email Parsing - Simple vs Multipart Emails

Tags: python-3.x, email, html-email, email-attachments

I am learning to parse emails and have run into a problem with multipart emails. I sent myself a simple text email saying "Hi Inbox, This is a simple sample email :)", downloaded it as an eml file and tried to parse it. But it shows up as a multipart email with HTML. How can I resolve this?

My code and the output given
[image: My code and the output given]

Comment: Emails are usually sent with both HTML and plain text. That's normal. The email provider at the customer end will choose which one to display.

Comment: Hi Nathan! So both formats are present in all emails? Is there a way to parse emails such that it shows up only as text, cause this is a little reduntant?

Comment: Not in all. You should be able to send just plain text. I don't know python to be able to reconstruct that - but if you did want help on that part, it would be best to copy the code as code, rather than an image. It also looks like you've given only part of it, so it's going to be hard to debug. Try and give a minimal amount of code to fully reproduce the problem.